# Certain programs disable second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, evolution

For some strange reason, whenever I open the Evolution mail client my second monitor gets disabled. If I unplug and re-plug it in, it is still blank. When I run `xrandr` I see:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   (...)
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   (...)
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I close Evolution, and re-plug my second monitor in, it works fine.

Interestingly, when Evolution is closed, and I run `xrandr`, my second monitor gets disabled again.

The same thing will happen if I run `screenfetch` (the two monitor setup works fine, but when running `screenfetch` the second monitor will be disabled)

After running `screenfetch` and `xrandr`, if I unplug and re-plug my monitor in, it works fine.

Any thoughts on where to begin debugging this and what could possibly be going on? I am running Ubuntu 20.04 focal
CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ @ 8x 2.8GHz
GPU: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)

Edit: my second monitor also gets disabled if I play a video

Comment: What is the make/model of the external monitor? Can you clarify: when you say the monitor is disabled, does `xrandr` still show DP-1 connected? And does Ubuntu display settings still show the monitor as active? e.g. is it going completely "missing" from the system or just going blank and the system still thinks it's there and mouse can still go off the laptop screen onto the blank monitor etc?

Comment: It's a Samsung 24" LS24D330HSL/ZA. When the monitor is disabled it just goes blank. `xrandr` shows that DP-1 is still connected, and the display settings shows it as a second monitor. My windows don't get rearranged if they were on the second screen. I am able to move my mouse over to it, and it takes some time for it to return to the active screen so I think that monitor is "active" just not displaying

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would try adding a custom mode to your desired monitor resolution but using what's called "reduced blanking". If it does not fix it then at least you have eliminated a possible cause.

First use `cvt` to generate a modeline on your system:

`cvt -r 1920 1080`

In my case I get this result:

```
# 1920x1080 59.93 Hz (CVT 2.07M9-R) hsync: 66.59 kHz; pclk: 138.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync
```

Then create a new xrandr mode using your resulting modeline  (omitting the "Modeline" keyword) so in my case it would be:

`xrandr --newmode "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync`

Now apply it to your DisplayPort `DP-1` output:

`xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1080R`

More details here including how to make permanent if it helps: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr

Comment: Sadly after going through these steps, and then running `screenfetch` or opening up Screen Display settings my second monitor still goes blank