# Unable to set 1920x1080 resolution on Ubuntu 22.10 with Intel HD Graphics 4400 and VGA display

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor, vga, xorg.conf

I have a PC with dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.10. I have an external TV as a monitor that is connected via VGA cable, and I know both the TV and VGA are perfectly capable of 1920x1080 because it works on Windows 10. However, when I try to set the display to 1920x1080 on Ubuntu's Settings -> Displays, the screen just blinks and reverts back to the old resolution.

I have the following system information from hardinfo:

```sql
    Operating System: Ubuntu 22.10
    CPU: Intel(R) Care(TM) i3-4130t CPU @ 2.90Ghz 1 physical process, 2 cores; 4 threads
    RAM: 3920360 KiB
    Motherboard: Hewlett-Packard 21D0
    Graphics: 1680x1050 Mesa intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2) The X.Org Foundation
    Storage: ATASTS001_7012-PWS14
    Audio: HISA-Intel-FICA Intel PCH
```

The contents of my xorg.conf file are:

```yaml
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
    Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1680x1050_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device "Device0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1680x1050_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And when I run $ xrandr, I get the following output:

```sql
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96 +
   1680x1050_60.00  59.95* 
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

How can I get 1920x1080 on Ubuntu 22.10?"

Comment: See my previous post here about `cvt/Modelines` with reduced blanking. I would try that and/or try a normal `Modeline` but reduce the refresh rate down from 60: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337869/certain-programs-disable-second-monitor/1338095#1338095

Comment: @codlord, I just wanted to reach out and say a huge thank you for your help with my resolution problem. Your advice was spot on and I was finally able to resolve the issue. I really appreciate the time and effort you took to help me out. Thank you again!
Can you please add your answer so that I can accept it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Get a `Modeline` using `Reduced blanking`:

`cvt -r 1920 1080 60`

Which will result in something like:

```
# 1920x1080 59.93 Hz (CVT 2.07M9-R) hsync: 66.59 kHz; pclk: 138.50 MHz 
Modeline "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync
```

Then take the second line from that, remove the word `Modeline` and issue a `xrandr --newmode` command like:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync
```

Finally change to that mode:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080R
```

See here for more info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr